# keep Hyperlink when copying row using script

Tags: hyperlink

Certain cell in rows have hyperlink. need hyperlink to follow row when copied from sheet to sheet based on other cell value

```
function moveToTab() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  Logger.log(col);
  var aSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var header = aSheet.getRange(10,col,1,1).getValue();
  Logger.log(header);
  if (header.toLowerCase() !== 'issued to') return;
  var target = range.getValue();
  if (target.toString().trim() === '') return;
  if (target.toString().toLowerCase() === aSheet.getName().toLowerCase()) return;
   var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var tSheet = sheets.filter(function(sheet) {
      if (sheet.getName().toLowerCase() == target.toLowerCase()) return true;
      else return false;
    })[0];
    if (!tSheet) return;
    var row = range.getRow();
    var values = aSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, aSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    tSheet.appendRow(values[0]);
    aSheet.deleteRow(row);
```

I know I am missing something simple. In my work book column "F" has a hyperlink to files. I am using the above script to move certain rows from sheet to sheet based on value in Column "K" and would like the hyper link in the cell in column "F" to follow teh row from sheet to sheet. What am i missing